# Getting Socket Data in Python

Tags: python, networking

(I'm writing this in python)

I've been stuck on this for a while now :
I am writing a UDP collector(in python) that data is being sent to.  However, I cannot get the correct data from it.  One of my coworkers has written a UDP collector (in golang) and receives the below output : (key difference will be bolded)

%!(EXTRA chan_service.Request={1501844689333211815 0 STATS user-master-01 172.22.64.123 30 true **[8 1 16 10 24 100 32 232 7]**})

I however get this data :

{"unix_time":1501844534270295150,"proto_name":"STATS","host_name":"user-master-01","host_ip":"172.22.64.123","expiration":30,"is_delta":true,"tm_data":"**CAEQChhkIOgH**"}

Any ideas on why I'm not receiving the same entry for tm_data as he is?

Here is my code :

```
def udp_port_data(port):

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind(("", port))
    print "\n\nThe connection to the port has been established\n\n"

    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(65535)
    print "\n\nThe data has been received from the port\n\n"

    print "The data is : ", data

    sock.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `tm_data` is base64 encoded and the Go implementation is decoding it to a list of numbers. I get the same result with this:

```
import json
import base64

data = '{"unix_time":1501844534270295150,"proto_name":"STATS","host_name":"mhegglin-master-01","host_ip":"172.22.64.123","expiration":30,"is_delta":true,"tm_data":"CAEQChhkIOgH"}'

x = json.loads(data)
print [ord(c) for c in base64.decodestring(x['tm_data'])]
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped!

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with my code, I find this works better for my purposes.

```
buff = json_data["tm_data"].decode('base64', "strict")
```

Still, thank you for figuring out it was encoded in base64!